# How to find the max value from a list of dicts based on different keys in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

I have below list of dicts

```
[{
    'NAV': 50,
    'id': '61e6b2a1d0c32b744d3e3b2d'
}, {
    'NAV': 25,
    'id': '61e7fbe2d0c32b744d3e6ab4'
}, {
    'NAV': 30,
    'id': '61e801cbd0c32b744d3e7003'
}, {
    'NAV': 30,
    'id': '61e80663d0c32b744d3e7c51'
}, {
    'NAV': 30,
    'id': '61e80d9ad0c32b744d3e8da6'
}, {
    'NAV': 30,
    'id': '61e80f5fd0c32b744d3e93f0'
}, {
    'NAV': 30,
    'id': '61e90908d0c32b744d3ea967'
}, {
    'NAV': 30,
    'id': '61ea7cf3d0c32b744d3ed1b2'
}, {
    'NAV': 50,
    'id': '61fa387127e14670f3a67194'
}, {
    'NAV': 30,
    'id': '61fa3cea27e14670f3a6772c'
}, {
    'Amount': 30,
    'id': '61e6b373d0c32b744d3e3d14'
}, {
    'Amount': 30,
    'id': '61e6b49cd0c32b744d3e3ea0'
}, {
    'Amount': 25,
    'id': '61e7fe90d0c32b744d3e6ccd'
}, {
    'Amount': 20,
    'id': '61e80246d0c32b744d3e7242'
}, {
    'Amount': 20,
    'id': '61e80287d0c32b744d3e74ae'
}, {
    'Amount': 20,
    'id': '61e80253d0c32b744d3e733e'
}, {
    'Amount': 34,
    'id': '61e80697d0c32b744d3e7edd'
}, {
    'Amount': 20,
    'id': '61e806a3d0c32b744d3e7ff9'
}, {
    'Amount': 30,
    'id': '61e80e0ad0c32b744d3e906e'
}, {
    'Amount': 30,
    'id': '61e80e22d0c32b744d3e9198'
}, {
    'Amount': 20,
    'id': '61e81011d0c32b744d3e978e'
}, {
    'Amount': 20,
    'id': '61e8104bd0c32b744d3e9a92'
}, {
    'Amount': 20,
    'id': '61e81024d0c32b744d3e98cd'
}, {
    'Amount': 20,
    'id': '61e90994d0c32b744d3eac2b'
}, {
    'Amount': 20,
    'id': '61e909aad0c32b744d3ead76'
}, {
    'Amount': 50,
    'id': '61fa392a27e14670f3a67337'
}, {
    'Amount': 50,
    'id': '61fa393727e14670f3a67347'
}, {
    'Amount': 50,
    'id': '61fa3d6727e14670f3a67750'
}, {
    'Amount': 150,
    'id': '61fa3d7127e14670f3a67760'
}]
```

Above list contains dict which has key as `NAV` and `Amount`. I need to find the max value separately among all the dicts for NAV and Amount. So that output is

```
NAV = 50
Amount = 150
```

I have tried some approach like:

```
max(outList, key=lambda x: x['NAV'])
```

But this is giving me keyerror of 'NAV'. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: maybe because "Current NAV ($ M)" doesn't exist ?

Comment: this is because NAV is not present in every dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with your `max` solution:

assuming your list is called `outList` (BTW, that is not a pythonic name, try `out_list` instead)

```
nav = max(outList, key=lambda item: item.get("NAV", float("-inf")))['NAV']
amount = max(outList, key=lambda item: item.get("Amount", float("-inf")))['Amount']
```

Comment: What does `-1_000_000` means?

Comment: @SAndrew `dict.get` will return nothing if the key isn't in your dict (not all your dict have NAV or Amount). You can pass a second parameter that will be returned instead of the `None` and in our case we are doing numerical comparison so we dont want our keys to be compared to `None`. I chose -1000000 as a small enough number that it (hopefully) wont be in your list.

Comment: That one needs to “hope” the numbers satisfy an arbitrary property means this is not a robust solution at all

Comment: @donkopotamus are you referring to the `-1000000`? because I have already added `-inf` as to the solution

Comment: @Nullman … why continue to insist on having something arbitrary to compare values with if the key does not exist?  It means the answer does not generalise to arbitrary types non comparable to `float` (Eg `date`, `tuple`,`str`).  Just use `in` to filter the iterable and it’s generalised.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
print max([i["NAV"] for i in t if "NAV" in i])
print max([i["Amount"] for i in t if "Amount" in i])
```

Result:

```
50
150
```

```
def max_from_list(t_list, key):
    return max([i[key] for i in t_list if key in i])
```

Comment: Downvoted as technically **wrong** if dicts contain eg negatives and **zeroes** … use eg `… if “NAV” in i`

Comment: @donkopotamus, thank you for the remark, it was on the point ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are calling `Current NAV ($ M)`. It doesn't exist in the list you have provided. Anyway, I came up with the code below:

```py
def getMax(value):
  if "NAV" in value:
    return value["NAV"]
  else:
    return value["Amount"]
  
max(outList, key= getMax)
```

If you are interested in finding the max value for `NAV` and `Amount` separately, you can try filtering the list out and then calling the lambda as you used before.

```
print(max([x["NAV"] for x in outList if "NAV" in x]))
print(max([x["Amount"] for x in outList if "Amount" in x])
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are not only looking for NAV and Amount, maybe you can do as below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)

for i in d:
    for k, v in i.items():
        if k != 'id':
            res[k] = max(res.get(k, 0), v)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).